# Applications of amenable groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, amenability

I will do a talk about amenablity for a public of master students who are mainly interested in algebraic geometry and mathematical physics. At the end, I would like to include some links with some subjects which are closer to their interest, maybe Lie groups, cohomology or even better algebraic geometry stuff (if it exists) ?

I would be really happy with any reference which explains any of these links (again if it exists). It doesn't have to be too long since I have 45 minutes and I will probably spend the first 30 minutes to explain the basics (Banach-Tarski paradox as a motivation, Tarski theorem, some examples, the fixed-point criterion and some general properties ... )

Thanks for any reference/comment !

Comment: Last year, I had a course relating amenable groups with [cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). It was using [Cellular automata and groups by Ceccherini-Silberstein and Coornaert](http://www.math.univ-metz.fr/~gnc/bibliographie/Ceccherini-Silberstein,%20Coornaert.%20Cellular%20Automata%20and%20Groups.pdf)

Comment: Thanks ! I also learned basics of amenability in a book which was talking about cellular automata. This is a cool topic but I was hoping (maybe this is too much) for something more "abstract", like probability theory on Lie groups, cohomology of algebras or even better some relations to algebraic geometry since they all have a really good background in Lie theory and algebraic geometry.